# Is it safe to save admin (username and password) into react app

Tags: reactjs

I using the WordPress API to create new users. I send admin username and password with headers via Axios and basic authentication plugin. I think this is unsafe to put credentials in my code directly. Am I right? Should I save admin credentials another place in my React app?

Can the users see my credentials with page inspecting or another way?

please tell me the right way?

```
axios
  .post(`${BASE_URL}/wp-json/wp/v2/users/`, userData, {
     auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: '123456'
      }
})
```

Comment: yes its unsafe ,you should try to generate token after successful authentication and store that token in react app andt then use it for another api calls

Comment: Thanks, but to generate token I should send my admin credentials. Where should I save them in my react app?

Comment: assume you allow user to enter admin credentials,store that value initially in your redux store ,when login success unset that value.